# How to close one modal popup when another one is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I am trying to get a modal popup window from another modal popup window.
when i click the link from the first popup window, the second popup window is opening, but the first one not getting closed.

How can i do this?

jQuery:

```
 $(".get-me-license").click(function(){
    $("#license").modal('show');
 });

 $(".confirm-my-license").click(function(){
    $("#confirm-license").modal('show');
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="license" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img class="modal-cont" src="images/license-popup.png">

                <table class="get-license-confirm"> 
                  <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning confirm-my-license">GET LICENSE</a></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div id="confirm-license" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img class="modal-cont" src="images/license-popup.png">

                <table class="get-license-confirm"> 
                  <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Confirm</a></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I hope you need   ` $('#myModal').modal('hide'); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this two methods**

To hide the modal:

```
$('.YourModalElement').modal('hide');
```

Or to totally destroy the modal instance, you can try this one:

```
$('.YourModalElement').data('modal', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

put common class in all modal and just call  modal funtion with hide argument befor show new modal.  Like this :

suppose common class for modal is  "common-modal".

```
$('.common-modal').modal('hide');
```

then

```
$('yourmodal').modal();
```